# Sonarqube Error

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Sonarqube error in VSTS Build when version 4 of sonar extension is used.

Error -

> [SQ] API GET. '/api/server/version' failed, error was:
>   {"code":"UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY"} .

SonarQube extension version 3 build runs successfully. 
We are using **Sonarqube version 7.1**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, read the [ask] page and update your question. Do you use HTTPS for example.

Comment: Yes we use https

Comment: Did you import the Certificate in java as a Trusted Certificate?

Comment: @jeroen i get this same error on Prepare analysis task. Could you please elaborate on the certificate part?.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/vsts-publish-quality-gate-result-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate/14384/4) discussion.

Answer (score 0):

**I also faced same error:**
[error][SQ] API GET '/api/server/version' failed, error was: {"code":"UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY"

**To fix this issue:**

First I installed Java 17 to devOps build agent machine  https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk17-archive-downloads.html
Java SE Development Kit 17.0.5  Windows x64 Installer.
Installed path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.5

Then add two devOps build pipeline variables:
NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS and SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS

[image]

SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS:
Copy your cacerts and replace existing one.
path: “…\Java\jdk 17.0.5\lib\security\cacerts”

Then add both paths in devOps SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS variable:

-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\program files\Java\jdk 17.0.5\lib\security\cacerts"
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="C:\program files\Java\jdk 17.0.5\lib\security\cacerts"

NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS:
copy your cert *.PEM file and replace it the existing one in devops build agent path: C:\devOps_Agent\sonarchain.pem

After this step SonarQube prepare starting to work.